# How to add Autocomplete on a search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search, autocomplete, pagination

may I ask how can I add an autocomplete for my simple search engine.

Below is the Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of your search engine</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='search.php' method='GET'>
<center>
<h1>My Search Engine</h1>
<input type='text' size='90' name='search'></br></br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search source code' ></br></br></br>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the search.php

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
$m_Host = "localhost"; 
$m_User = "root"; 
$m_Pass = "Kyrene"; 
$m_Db = "ensemble";

$connect = mysql_connect($m_Host,$m_User,$m_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<br />";

mysql_select_db($m_Db,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
error_reporting(error_reporting()&~E_NOTICE);

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND title LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM test WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1. 
Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website'
then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</br>2. Try different words with similar
 meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling";
else
{ 

echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

$per_page = 1;
$start = $_GET['start'];
$max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];

echo "
<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
$desc<br>
<a href='$url'>$url</a><p>
";

}

//Pagination Starts
echo "<center>";

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

$adjacents = 3;
$last = $max_pages - 1;

if($max_pages > 1)
{   
//previous button
if (!($start<=0)) 
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$prev'>Prev</a> ";    

//pages 
if ($max_pages < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
{
$i = 0;   
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}  
$i = $i + $per_page;                 
}
}
elseif($max_pages > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
{
//close to beginning; only hide later pages
if(($start/$per_page) < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
{
$i = 0;
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;                                       
}

}
//in middle; hide some front and some back
elseif($max_pages - ($adjacents * 2) > ($start / $per_page) && ($start / $per_page) > ($adjacents * 2))
{
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                 
for ($counter = ($start/$per_page)+1; $counter < ($start / $per_page) + $adjacents + 2; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}   
$i = $i + $per_page;                
}

}
//close to end; only hide early pages
else
{
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                
for ($counter = ($start / $per_page) + 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";   
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;              
}
}
}

//next button
if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page))
echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&submit=Search+source+code&start=$next'>Next</a> ";    
}   
echo "</center>";
} 
} 
?>
```

I don't really have idea how should i start it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I will give you the general shpill of how to do it. 1. Use ajax to fetch data. 2. present data. if you are using jQuery $("#search").autocomplete(
  {
   source : function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
     type : 'get',
     url : "http://hostname.com/suggest.php",
     data : {
      str : document.getElementById("search").value
     },
     success : function(result) {
      response(result.list);
     },
     dataType : 'json',
     global : false
    });
   }
  });

Comment: Don't Forget to `Real_Escape` it first!!!

Comment: You can use jquery autocomplete or typeahead.js

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the general shpill of how to do it. 1. Use ajax to fetch data. 2. present data. if you are using jQuery

```
$("#search").autocomplete(
{
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : "http://hostname.com/suggest.php",
                data : {
                    search : document.getElementById("search").value
                },
                success : function(result) {
                    response(result.list);
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                global : false
            });
        }
    });
```

in your suggest.php

```
<?php
 $str = $_GET['search'];
 //query database, get results
 echo json_encode(array('list'=>$mydata));
?>
```

and the id='search' to your search input tag